# Change picture while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I´m doing a project where I want a in image inside a div to change while scrolling. I have no code to start with but I have en example.

I have tried to google, but I can´t seem to find anywhere that explains how to do this.

In this article if you scroll for a bit, you can see what I mean on the right hand side.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/special/2014/newsspec_8703/index.html

Please let me know if anyone knows how to do this.

Comment: You can use jquery `offset()`  for this waht you can find here: http://api.jquery.com/offset/ . When the offset is at a certain point, change the image. You can also take a look at jquery .`scrollTop()` http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: You can do this with CSS, use fixed position background images.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/) on how to make a similar background type (with download of source)

This uses CSS to create a fixed and scroll backgrounds. using the CSS background-attachment property set on fixed.

It has [a demo](http://codyhouse.co/demo/alternate-fixed-scroll-background/index.html) as well to see if that is what you are looking for, as well as a fairly straight-forward explanation on how it is done on the main page of the article.

Comment: That is not what he was talking about at all.